# Comment character for OpenWRT's UCI system

Tags: openwrt

What is the proper syntax for (single and multi-line) comments in [OpenWRT's UCI System](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci)?  Do they vary by section or setting?

For example, `/etc/config/fstab`:

```
config global
    option anon_swap '0'
    option anon_mount '0'
    option auto_swap '1'
    option auto_mount '1'
    option delay_root '5'
    option check_fs '1'
```

Should I use `#` or `--` or `\\`?

Comment: I never gave it much thought but I've always used `#` at the beginning of each line.

Comment: I might not have the newest `uci` code at hand but in `uci_parse_line` they explicitly `return` without doing anything if `#` is the first non-whitespace character in the line.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk correction: They return even if `#` is not the first non-whitespace character, it can be anywhere on the line. Note that it should be preceded by a whitespace character.